# How to set the crossContext flag programatically in servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, struts2

I want to know how to set the crossContext flag true??

I'm using tomcat server and i used to set the context file in tomcat server. But now it'll be war and i want to set the crossContext flag programatically while starting the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that if you need to use crossContext to communicate between contexts, your application design is simply wrong. You should instead create a central communication point that is context independent. A singleton class instance for example

Comment: Why do you (a) need `crossContext="true"`, (b) want to do it programmatically (instead of through configuration) and (c) not post any code you have already tried?